# QStringList contains throwing error

Tags: c++, qt, qstringlist

I've got a string I want to compare to the contents of a `QStringList`.

My string is held in `test[1]` and my `QStringList` is `imagez`.

I believe the `QStringList::contains` is what I need to use but I'm getting an error.

```
if(imagez::contains(test[1]) == true){
    foundFiles << file;
}
```

Error:

> expected a class or namespace

Can someone help me out here please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `imagez` is a pointer to an object, not a class name, you want the `->` operator not the namespace qualifier (`::`). Like this:

```
if(imagez->contains(test[1]))
```

No need to compare booleans for equality to `true`.

Comment: Awesome, I'm new to all these pointers and then trying to find my way through all the QT documentation is slow! I know what I want to do, just gotta find a way to do it, thanks bud.